# Get nested inner content value of each div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get selected values of all the radio buttons and if one is not selected, then null value.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="question m-2">
    <div class="question-title">Question 1</div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-1">Option a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-1">Option b
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-1">Option c
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-1">Option d
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question m-2">
    <div class="question-title">Question 2</div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-2">Option a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-2">Option b
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-2">Option c
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-2">Option d
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question m-2">
    <div class="question-title">Question 3</div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-3">Option a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-3">Option b
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-3">Option c
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-3">Option d
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to store all the answers of each question, if selected then the selected value, if not selected, then null value. Can anyone help me with jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the answers like this:

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
  let questions = $(".question");
  let answers = [];
  let answer;
  questions.each(function() {
     if ($(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").length) {
        answer = $(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
     } else {
        answer = "null";
     }        
     answers.push(answer);
  });
  console.log(answers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question m-2">
    <div class="question-title">Question 1</div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-1">Option a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-1">Option b
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-1">Option c
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-1">Option d
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question m-2">
    <div class="question-title">Question 2</div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-2">Option a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-2">Option b
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-2">Option c
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-2">Option d
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="question m-2">
    <div class="question-title">Question 3</div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-3">Option a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-3">Option b
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-3">Option c
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-3">Option d
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="submit">
Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with `javascript` as well

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
const answers = Array.from(questions).map(e => e.querySelector('input.form- 
      check - input: checked ').value);
```

In JQuery

```js
const answers = $('.question input.form-check-input:checked').val();
```